# Android Best Way to do Multicolumn ListView using Percentage Sizing

Tags: android, android-listview

I have tried the recommended approach for percentage sizing of rows in LinearLayout using layout_weight, with no success when wrapped in a ListView. The row layout XML looks fine in Eclipse preview, but the columns are run together in the actual test app.

However, if I wrap the ListView in a TableLayout and TableRow, then it works.

Attached is the main view layout XML that works.  If you remove TableLayout and TableRow by removing the comment tags, it fails.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Are there better ways to do this?

===== Row Layout =====

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- row.xml -->
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:weightSum="100"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/one"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="25"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:text="One"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/two"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="25"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:text="Two"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/three"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="50"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:text="Three"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

===== Main Layout =====

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" > 
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainlist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0"
        android:paddingTop="4px" >
        <TableRow>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ListView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the table layout and tablerow and just set your ListView layout_width to match_parent

edit: or match_parent or fill_parent, they are synonymous.

Comment: what specifically did not work? I just tried it on a galaxy nexus and it did pretty well.

Comment: Yeah, that did it. Boy do I feel dumb. I changed it on the wrong element. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you tried to say layout_weight instead of layout_gravity because it doesn't do that.

Try removing the first layout_weightSum in the listview and replace the weights of each column to be like this:

.25 in the first column
.25 in the second column
1 in the third column.

The number one will make the column stretch to fill the gap

EDIT:

I meant this:

What I understood is that you want to create a linear layout with three columns. Two of those columns should take half of the screen space where the third one should stretch to fill the other half.

This linear layout should be the layout of the single item of each item of the listview, is that what you want?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- row.xml -->
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/one"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_weight=".25"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:text="One"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/two"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_weight=".25"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:text="Two"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/three"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:text="Three"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is one of my own:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- row.xml -->
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     style="@style/ListViewItem"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/currencyName"
         style="@style/ListViewItemSubtitle"
         android:layout_width="110dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/currencyCode"
         style="@style/ListViewItemSubtitle"
         android:layout_width="60dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight=".2"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/currencyExchangeRate"
         style="@style/ListViewItemSubtitle"
         android:layout_width="90dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight=".25"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, I meant weight. If you mean to remove the TableLayout and TableRow, and then make the other changes you described, it did not work. I assume it will work outside of the ListView/LinearLayout/ hierarchy, but it doesn't seem to work within it.

Comment: But you have an explicit width specified in each TextView item. Doesn't that conflict with the weight?